# swagger-ui trying to download index.html

Tags: spring, swagger, swagger-ui

I'm running into an issue where swagger-ui is trying to download the index.html page when I navigate to it in the browser instead of displaying it as an html page. Can't figure out what is causing this.

I'm using Swagger 1.3.4 with Spring.

Spring Config:

```
@Configuration
public class SwaggerConfig {

@Bean
public BeanConfig beanConfig() {
    final BeanConfig beanConfig = new BeanConfig();
    beanConfig.setResourcePackage("com.example.rest.ws");
    beanConfig.setVersion("1.0");
    beanConfig.setBasePath("my-rest-services");
    beanConfig.setTitle("My API");
    beanConfig.setScan(true);
    return beanConfig;
}
```

}

I then make a request to the following in the browser:

```
https://example.com/my-rest-services/swagger-ui/index.html
```

And it tries to download the index.html file. I check the Response Headers and they are as follows:

```
 Accept-Ranges:bytes
 Age:2000
 Connection:Keep-Alive
 Content-Length:3467
 Content-Type:application/octet-stream
 Date:Fri, 24 Aug 2017 15:15:23 GMT
 Server:Apache-Coyote/1.1
```

Why would Swagger return an octet-stream Content-Type?

Answer (score 0):

It is the web server which sets the content-type response header. From your response headers it appears apache is the web server.

In Apache, the mappings between MIME types and file extensions are stored in the configuration file apache_home/conf/mime.types, where apache_home is the path under which Apache was installed on your server.

Open the mime.types file in a text editor and check whether the mapping for html files exists as below:

text/html html htm

where, text/html is the mime type and html,htm are the file extensions.